# RequestDispatcher instantiates servlet which has already been instantiated via load-on-startup

Tags: tomcat, servlets, requestdispatcher

I have a Servlet which is annotated like this:

```
@WebServlet(value="/MyServiceServlet", loadOnStartup=1)
```

This results in the Servlet being instantiated on application start and its `init()` method being called. Perfect! (In the `init()` method, a Thread is started to perform some db maintenance which runs each hour)

Now, on certain end user actions, I reach the Servlet by using 
`getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/MyServiceServlet").include(request, response)` to trigger some other db stuff, but the first time I try this, my Servlet gets instantiated one more time and the `init()` method is called (of course), which results in two similar Threads running. Not perfect!

It seems as if the `loadOnStartup=1` does not put the Servlet in the Servlet Context, hence when I try to reach it by the Request Dispatcher it needs to be instantiated.

How can this be? How to fix so I just get one instance of my Servlet? I need it to be started along the application, as the Service started in the `init()` should run immediately.

The application is deployed on Tomcat 7.0.57.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Tomcat. What if you get the RequestDispatcher via HttpServletRequest itself the usual way? Getting it via ServletContext is only necessary when it's in a different ServletContext (i.e another webapp deployed on same server; you then usually get the ServletContext of interest via ServletContext#getContext()).

Comment: @BalusC I have tried to both use the request object to get the RequestDispatcher and use pre 3.x methodology to map the Servlet through web.xml to no avail. After a bit more debugging, it seems to be the call to .include(request, response) that creates yet another instance of my Servlet.

Answer (score 0):

> (In the init() method, a Thread is started to perform some db
>   maintenance which runs each hour)

O good lord, wonderful, do you even believe in memory leak? running a thread in servlet?! you need to do it by context-listener(`javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`), not directly, it's not safe.

```
public class run_thread implements ServletContextListener{
    @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {System.out.println("Init: daemon stuffs");/*run teh trhead*/}
        @Override public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            System.out.println("Hult: daemon stuffs");/*hult teh trhead*/
        }
    }
```

and don't forge to register it bi `web.xml`

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>pack.run_thread</listener-class>
</listener>
```

More better solution let another external application do db maintain, or at least invoke the servlet path to do so intervally.

> Now, on certain end user actions, I reach the Servlet by using

What is the user action? how? using another servlet? what about `requets.getRequestDispatcher()` instead of `getServletContext()`

You may share the servlet code, would be appreciated.